# Dynamic routing in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I do the following in Laravel 5.1:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', ['as' => $user, 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
```

The code above gives an error:

```
Undefined variable: user
```

Comment: Maybe you should define `$user`

Comment: @V4n1ll4 you are trying to use variable that is not currently defined enywhere

Comment: I am trying to define it with `{user}`

Comment: You can't do that and you don't it though. What's your aim?

Comment: The `as` directive in the route parameters describes a name for the route. It has nothing to do with the parameters in the route. So what you're trying to do there doesn't make sense. Check out [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing) and then come back & describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: `as` should be a string, i.e. `'as' => 'user.show'`. It is the name of the route, it is not what the value of the `{user}` parameter should be. For that, check out [route–model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-model-binding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing fails because you defined a $user variable as the route name, so Laravel returns an error.

Route names are useful for reverse routing, as an example when you define redirect or action attribute in your form.

Check the documentation to know how to pass variable by routes.

EDIT:
Here the link to the doc for Laravel 5.1 ( which is similar to previous version btw ). A good practice is passibg the variable or an array of variables using a closure.

```
Route::get( '/users/{user}', function( $user ) {
return $user;});
```

And this one using correct route naming:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', ['as' => 'userroute', function( $user ) {
return $user;}]);
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters

Comment: hoe does Laravel define the `$user` variable in the closure ? I think `$user` means `user_id` instead of an object, right ?